# Add a value to y:axis if all the values are Zero after filtering

Tags: javascript

Have a JavaScript Which removes Duplicates of labels `label:'Adnim'` and count only "1" `y:1,` by Skipping Zeros"0" `y:0,` this is Working perfect but the issue is if all the values of a particular label are zero then for that labes it gives output nothing.

Example:1

```
       {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
       {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
        {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
        {y:1,label:'Adnim'},//Value of y:1  is one all are zero 
      {y:0,label:'Adnim2'},
     {y:0,label:'Adnim2'},
       {y:1,label:'Adnim2'},
      {y:1,label:'Adnim2'},
```

Current Output:

```
      {y:1,label:'Adnim'},
      {y:2,label:'Adnim2'},
```

Example:2

```
       {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
       {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
        {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
        {y:0,label:'Adnim'},//Value of y:0  is all are zero 
      {y:0,label:'Adnim2'},
     {y:0,label:'Adnim2'},
       {y:1,label:'Adnim2'},
      {y:1,label:'Adnim2'},
```

Current Output:

```
      {y:2,label:'Adnim2'},
```

Expected Output:

```
     {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
      {y:2,label:'Adnim2'},
```

Javscript:

```
 var list = [
  {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
   {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
    {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
    {y:1,label:'Adnim'},
  {y:0,label:'Adnim2'},
 {y:0,label:'Adnim2'},
   {y:1,label:'Adnim2'},
  {y:1,label:'Adnim2'},
]

var counters = {}
var result = [];
var resultString = '';
var label;

list.forEach(function(el){
    label = el.label;
    // Skip zero y's
    if (el.y === 0) return;

    // Increase counter values
    if (counters.hasOwnProperty(label)) {
        counters[label] += 1;
    } else {
        counters[label] = 1;
    }
});

// Convert counters object to array of objects
for (var label in counters) {
    result.push({'label': label, 'y': counters[label]});
}

// Render result to the target div
console.log(result);

result = result.map(function(el){ return '{y: ' + el.y + ', label: "' + el.label + '"}' });
resultString = '[' + result.join(', ') + ']';
$('#target').html(resultString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are no items with y==0, you never create a counters entry. Try the following replacement for your forEach function (tested in Chrome):

```
list.forEach(function(el) {
    label = el.label;

    // Init the counters entry if necessary
    if (!counters.hasOwnProperty(label)) 
        counters[label] = 0;

    if (el.y !== 0)
        counters[label] += 1;
});
```

Comment: if replaced nothing is Showing up

Comment: Edited to use a forEach with no return (also neater code). I've tested this in Chrome and it works.

Comment: i am getting an output, but i know that is NOT what is expected. Just to make it more accurate. If i have all the labels value as zero, then i need a output as {y:0,label:'Adnim'}. A single value for zero, request you to help me here http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/PzCEN/#&togetherjs=6s4hBkupTE

Comment: if am changing to this OUTPUT is NULL

Comment: @Shaik, which browser are you using? I've made another edit above, which works fine in your JSFiddle on Chrome.

Comment: And Firefox and IE (the original didn't work in IE for some reason, this one does)

Comment: can i seek your help for at least  5mnts  in fiddle if u dont mind http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/PzCEN/#&togetherjs=6s4hBkupTE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80145/discussion-between-shaik-and-alan).

Comment: if u don't mind have a quick question if in case have to skip ones"1" What should b replaced